# create dropdown example in laravel from existnig dropdown list

Tags: laravel-5

I want to try for dependent dropdown in laravel 5.
In which main dropdown having several lists like(Electronics,Automobiles) and from one of them click or change event.
I want to create another whole dropdown .
if I clicked on Electronics than one another dropdown will be Automatic generated for electronics.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8fre.png)
If I clicked on electronics from first dropdown list at that time another dropdown will be automatically generated for the electornics.
and than if i clicked Automobiles from first dropdown list than it should replace the last automatically created dropdown which is for electronics.

Comment: Please add some code and explain what do you want to achieve as an end result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Dependent Drop-down Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Dependent Drop-down Demo</h1>
<div class="container">
        {!! Form::open(['url'=>'Demo']  ) !!}   
        <div class="dropdown">
        <select name="category" id="category" class=" form-control">
            <option value=" "selected disabled>Select Category</option>
            @foreach($categories as $category)
                <option value='{{ $category->id }}' > {{$category->name}} </option>
            @endforeach
        </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <select hidden name="subcategory" id="subcategory" class=" form-control">
        </select>
        <select hidden name="semicategory" id="semicategory" class=" form-control">
        </select>


        </div>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>

<script>
$("#category").on('change', function(e){

    alert("test");
    console.log(e);
     $("#semicategory").hide();
    $("#subcategory").show();
    var category_id = e.target.value;
    var s = $('<select />');
       //ajax
        $.get('/index?category_id=' + category_id, function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $("#subcategory").empty();
            $.each(data, function(index, subcatObj){
            $("#subcategory").append('<option value ="'+ subcatObj.id +'">'+subcatObj.name+'</option>');
            });
        });
    });
  $("#subcategory").on('change', function(e){
        alert("hello");
        console.log(e);
        $("#semicategory").show();
        var subcategory_id = e.target.value;
        //ajax
        $.get('/index1?subcategory_id=' + subcategory_id, function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $("#semicategory").empty();
            $.each(data, function(index, subcatObj1){
                $("#semicategory").append('<option value ="'+ subcatObj1.id +'">'+subcatObj1.name+'</option>');
            });
        });
    // $("#subcategory").hide();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```